# How to get the full xml data returned by a sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a ms-sql query which is returning XML data. I am running that query in rails 3.1.1 like this:

```
xmlstring  = PurchaseOrder.find_by_sql(["select cast((select(SELECT * from purchase_orders for XML path('purchase_order'),type,elements xsinil)for xml path('purchase_orders'))as xml)as xmlcol])
```

where `PurchaseOrder` is a model. This query returns me the XML in the `xmlcol` column. But the retrieved XML is not complete and causing problems. I ran this code to know whether the XML is correct or not :

```
puts xmlstring[0].xmlcol
```

and came to the conclusion that my XML is not complete. And when I run the same query in sql server 2008 query editor, I get the full and correct XML.

edit 1 -

If XML which is expected is like -

```
<purchase_orders>
 <purchase_order>
  .
  .
 </purchase_order>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 <purchase_order>
  .
  .
 </purchase_order>
</purchase_orders>
```

But XML result is like that-

```
<purchase_orders>
  <purchase_order>
    .
    .
   </purchase_order>
   .
   .
   </purchase
```

which is incomplete and have only 2048 characters.

Comment: What is the result of the `puts`?

Comment: i got the solution by adding "set text 100000" in the beginning of the query.